# Problems with user state change

Tags: firebase, svelte, sveltekit

I'm using SvelteKit and trying to show and hide a link for the profile page.

When I log in the link appears, but when I log out the link doesn't hide.

I don't know if I have to use the onAuthStateChanged or do something more reactive in Svelte.

I put my code inside my component navBar.svelte:

```js
<script>
    import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
    $: auth = getAuth()
</script>  

 {#if auth.currentUser}
 <a sveltekit:prefetch href="/profile">
 <li class="navbarListItem">
 <img src="/assets/svg/RiUser3Line.svg" alt="perfil" width="36px" height="36px"/>
 <p>Profile</p>
 </li>
 </a>
{:else}
 <a sveltekit:prefetch href="/profile" style="display: none;">
 <li class="navbarListItem">
 <img src="/assets/svg/RiUser3Line.svg" alt="perfil" width="36px" height="36px" />
<p>Profile</p>
</li>
</a>
{/if}
```

Comment: You should always use an auth state listener if you want to immediately react to change in sign in state.  currentUser just gives you a point in time snapshot.

Comment: something like that? ``` onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
  // do something
   }
  } else {
  // do something
  }
 })```

Comment: This is all covered in the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data

Comment: In my forms that requires authentication I did it ```onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
   formData = {
    ...formData,
    user: user.uid
   }
  } else {
  }
 })```  I'm not figuring out what I need to do in this case.

Comment: That should be your question, then. Show what you tried that doesn't work the way you expect.  currentUser definitely won't work this way.